# How to increment score in Vanilla JS when a correct answer is typed into a textbox

Tags: javascript, function, input

I have a question that is answered by the user typing into a text box. When the answer is correct, how would I make the score go up by one? My JS is not working bc the score stays 0...

```
<p id="score">Score:</p>
<h3>Question 1:</h3>

<p>Where does skateboarding originate from?</p>
<input type="text" id="A1">
```

```
function keepScore() {
      if (document.getElementById("A1").value == "California") {
              score = score++
      }
}

keepScore()

document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score:" + score
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether you want to compute score at some final "submit" time (you would need a form submit button then), at input change or at typing.

Assuming you want the most live results (at typing), you need to re-compute the score from scratch every time a change is made in one of the answers inputs:

```js
function keepScore() {
  var score = 0
  if (document.getElementById("A1").value == "California") {
      score++
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerText = "Score:" + score
}
keepScore()
```

```html
<p id="score"></p>
<h3>Question 1:</h3>
<p>Where does skateboarding originate from?</p>
<input type="text" oninput="keepScore()" id="A1">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let score = 0;

function keepScore() {
 
  if (document.getElementById("A1").value === "California") {
    score = score + 1
  }
  document.getElementById("A1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score:" + score
}
```

```html
<p id="score">Score:0</p>
<h3>Question 1:</h3>
<p>Where does skateboarding originate from?</p>
<input type="text" id="A1" onchange="keepScore()">
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<p id="score">Score:</p>
<h3>Question 1:</h3>
<p>Where does skateboarding originate from?</p>
<input type="text" id="A1" onchange="keepScore()">
```

```js
function keepScore() {
    if (document.getElementById("A1").value == "California") {
        score = score++
    }

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score:" + score
}
```